# Showing $f(x)=\max_{u\in U} c^Tu+x^T(Au-b)$ is convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, subgradient

The following is an exercise from a test. I didn't solve it.

> Let $U$ be a compact, polyhedral set in $\mathbb R^n$ with vertices $u_1, u_2, \dots, u_n$, $A$ an $m \times n$ matrix and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let's define $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$.
>
> $$f(x) = \max_{u \in U} c^T u + x^T \left( A u - b \right)$$
>
> a) Show that $f$ is convex.
>
> b) Characterize the subgradient of $f$.

As for part a) I rearranged $f$ to$$f(x)=\max_{u\in U}(c^T+x^TA)u-x^Tb$$, now I think because the expression inside is linear the maximum will be attained at one of the vertices depending on $x$, $u_i(x)$, but I might be wrong, anyway help appreciated.

Comment: the maximum/supremum of convex functions is convex

Comment: To make (a) explicit, the easy point here is to see (i) that $\alpha f(x) = f(\alpha x)$, and (ii) if it were linear $f(x_1 + x_2) = f(x_1) + f(x_2)$ -- this isn't true but we can prove it is subadditive.  In combination that meets the definition of convexity. This is called quasi-linearization.  Because two choices are better than one,  for $p\in [0,1]$ and $q = 1-p$, you have $f(p x_1 + qx_2)= \max_{u\in U}\Big((pc^T+px_1^TA)u-p x_1^Tb + (qc^T+qx_2^TA)u-qx_2^Tb\Big) \leq \max_{u\in U}\Big((pc^T+px_1^TA)u-p x_1^Tb\Big) + \max_{u'\in U}\Big((qc^T+qx_2^TA)u'-qx_2^Tb\Big) = pf(x_1) + qf(x_2)$

Comment: @user8675309 Thank you for this comment, but  I am wondering why do you put $p$ into $pc^T$ expression? Should it not be $f(px_1+qx_2)=max_{u∈U}((c^T+px^T_1A)u−px^T_1b+(c^T+qx^T_2A)u−qx^T_2b)$?

Comment: Also I believe $\alpha f(x)=f(\alpha x)$ is not true. Lets take $c=1$, $A=1$ $b=1$ $U=[0,\frac{3}{2}]$, then $f(x)=\max_{u\in U}u+xu-1$, $f(1)=2$, $f(5)=8$.

Comment: Re: second comment you’re right I was sloppy in explanation-- I should have shown the argument first with the homogeneous $g(x) = \max_{u \in U}  x^T \left( A u - b \right)$ which does respect scaling and is subadditive. The motivation/idea is that the translation given by $c^T u$ doesn’t ultimately matter for convexity.  Your first comment/suggestion isn't true -- if you show your work you should be able to see that   $f(px_1+qx_2)=max_{u∈U}((c^T+px^T_1A)u−px^T_1b+(qx^T_2A)u−qx^T_2b) \neq max_{u∈U}((c^T+px^T_1A)u−px^T_1b+(c^T+qx^T_2A)u−qx^T_2b)$

Comment: So the ultimate question is why does the translation $c^Tu$ does not matter for convexity?  I do not see it. If you are right, then your argument is valid, but why?

Comment: No.  I stated that explicitly as "motivation/idea".  It is not required.  An unmotivated response is for you explicitly verify the following inequality: $f(p x_1 + qx_2)= \max_{u\in U}\Big((pc^T+px_1^TA)u-p x_1^Tb + (qc^T+qx_2^TA)u-qx_2^Tb\Big) $   $\leq \max_{u\in U}\Big((pc^T+px_1^TA)u-p x_1^Tb\Big) + \max_{u'\in U}\Big((qc^T+qx_2^TA)u'-qx_2^Tb\Big) = pf(x_1) + qf(x_2)$   and therefore $f$ is convex.  You need to unpack this and verify it is true.  It is just basic matrix vector algebra coupled with a basic result from analysis (i.e. 2 maxes or 2 sups being at least as big as one)